# Selecting and Sorting column values into columns in new DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that contains words and their bounding boxes on an image, the image is that of a table

```
df_text = pd.DataFrame({
    'words': ['Hello', 'world', 'nice day', 'have a', 'Greeting_1', 'Greeting_2'],
    'left': [1097, 1099, 258, 259, 1096, 260],
    'top': [1248, 1249, 1156, 1153,1200,250],
    'right': [1154, 1156, 615, 614, 1150, 610],
    'bottom': [1269, 1271, 1175, 1172, 1255, 1170] 
})
```

Which looks like this:

```
Words           left     top      right     bottom
hello           1097     1248     1154      1269
world           1099     1249     1156      1271
nice day        258      1156     615       1175
have a          259      1153     614       1172
Greeting_1      1096     1200     1150      1255
Greeting_2      260      250      610       1170
```

I now want to create a DataFrame that mimics the original image which looks like this:

```
Greeting_1            Greeting_2
hello                 Have a  
world                 nice day
```

So basically I want to select the column values of words that come under `Greeting_1` and make a new column out of it and want the same for `Greeting_2`. Generally the `left`, `top`, `right`, `bottom` values of `Greeting_1` and `Greeting_2` are lower than the words that come under it. `Greeting_1` and `Greeting_2` can appear in any order in the original dataframe.

Would appreciate some help in solving this problem.

Comment: Are the values correct? For example `Greeting_1` has right `1150` and `hello` has right `1154`

Comment: Yes the values are correct, they are a miniaturization of my original problem but they should be fine.

Comment: Basically the bounding boxes are supposed to represent the position of the top left and bottom right pixel on an image